# Ngnx and allow ports

Tags: nginx, ip, server

I want to allow the following IP addresses in Nginx but I do not understand the format given by the CDN, how do I use these?

```
146.88.136.0/21
94.31.33.128/27
64.125.78.224/27
94.31.33.192/27
64.125.78.192/27
198.232.124.0/22
27.50.79.130/32
50.31.251.34/32
108.161.176.0/20
64.125.76.96/27
94.31.33.160/27
64.125.102.96/27
64.125.102.64/27
216.12.211.59/32
50.31.249.226/32
119.81.131.131
70.39.132.0/24
64.125.102.32/27
64.125.76.64/27
64.125.78.96/27
216.12.211.60/32
27.50.77.226/32
119.81.131.130
146.88.128.0/21
174.36.204.195
174.36.204.196
37.58.110.67
37.58.110.68
158.85.206.228
158.85.206.231
94.46.144.0/20
94.31.56.160/27
94.31.27.64/27
177.54.148.0/24
185.18.207.65/26
```

Comment: This list does not contain ports. It is just a list of IP's and Subnets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list your CDN has given you is a list of CDIR formatted IP addresses which Nginx supports out of the box, you can simply state them as listed just prefix each with 'allow', ie:

```
allow 146.88.136.0/21;
allow 94.31.33.128/27;
allow 64.125.78.224/27;
allow 94.31.33.192/27;
```